# Displaying raster data export from temp folder using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, hillshade

I'm coming up against a fairly unusual raster display issue I haven't encountered before. As a caveat, I'm not the most experienced at working with display of raster data, so I assume (and hope) it's a simple solution.

I took a DEM and created a hillshade from it using the image analysis window, so far so good, made some adjustments to transparency & contrast. This was stored in my temp folder. The result:
[image: Just a background image for a map to add some depth]

When I exported to the folder I am keeping all my data, however, (right click temp layer in TOC etc., used default settings in export window) and added the resultant TIFF to the map, it looked like this:[image: Something's gone wrong]

Note that the original layer is still turned on- the only output was the black bands. I've calculated statistics for the layer hoping for a quick fix but no luck. The histogram seems to indicate there's some data there other than just black pixels in seemingly arbitrary strips.
[image: Histogram]

But there's definitely a clear trend in the data bunching up at the 180 mark.

Is there something incredibly obvious I'm missing? I'm not sure if this is a display issue or something unexpected happening to the data during the export process.

Using: ArcGIS 10.3 on Windows

Comment: What format were you converting from and to? How have you exported? Are both 8-bit unsigned integers? Are you applying compression to either? There is a problem with displaying BIL files where they look like that but are in fact ok, it's just a quirk of the display.. exporting to a different format might help.

Comment: From AFR (I wasn't aware this was the case- tbh I don't actually know what AFR is- as the original DEM was TIFF) and to TIFF. Both 8-bit unsigned, and no compression on either. Exported just through right click from TOC -> Data -> Export data.

Comment: So the original DEM is GeoTIFF and you did a right click export from ArcMap where the hillshade was displaying properly.. does it work any better using the HillShade tool from the toolbox http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000v0000000 directly to your intended location?

Comment: That definitely works as a workaround, thank you. I hadn't considered this route as the last time I had a look the organisation didn't have any Spatial Analyst licences available but lo and behold one of them had been freed up today. I also realised I hadn't calculated spatial stats on the original DEM- not sure if this might be the cause of the export issues. Much appreciated.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, it can be frustrating chasing an elusive extension license *for just 10 minutes*! If you find yourself needing a hillshade and no spatial analyst licenses available you could consider GDALDEM http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html as a viable alternative. Normally Esri is much better at *everything* than other products but in this one special case I prefer the hillshade by GDALDEM over the Esri hillshade... I think the GDAL produced raster is prettier.

Comment: Thanks again- I'm playing with some gaussian filtering on the original DEM in QGIS right now so I'll run the GDAL and see how it turns out.